# SimpleDB Incremental Index

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I understand SimpleDB doesn't have an auto increment but I am working on a script where I need to query the database by sending the id of the last record I've already pulled and pull all subsequent records. In a normal SQL fashion if there were 6200 records I already have 6100 of them when I run the script I query records with an ID greater than > 6100. Looking at the response object, I don't see anything I can use. It just seems like there should be a sequential index there. The other option I was thinking would be a real time stamp. Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using a timestamp was perfect for what I needed to do. I followed this article to help me on my way:http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1232 I would still welcome if anyone knows if there is a way to get an incremental index number.